# refresh Partial View after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have PartialView in Shared Folder OF my Mvc Project now I want After my Ajax call this Partial Be refresh.I use this:

$('#Footer').load('/Views/_FooterReport.cshtml');
and i get this error:

**GET http://localhost:2885/Views/_FooterReport.cshtml 500 (Internal Server Error)**

```
 <div id="updateAjax">
          some Table
        </div>
     <div class="btnContainer">
       some button here
        </div>
    <div id="Footer">
        @Html.Partial("_FooterReport")
        </div>

      $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: "html",
                    traditional: true,
                    data: parameters,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('#updateAjax').html(data);
                      //here How Can I Refresh or Reload my Partial in Footer
```

**('#Footer').load('/Views/_FooterReport.cshtml');**

```
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                    }

                });
```

Comment: you're getting a server error. debug the code to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Where is the route for accessing the current page? Use `.load()` on that route with #Footer at the end. `.load('currentRoute #Footer')`.

Comment: the partial is in shared folder of my mvc project for use in all page.currentRoute?????how can i access to it???

Comment: What is the URL for that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an MVC project. The requests will be run through a route system. Take the URL for this page (for example: `/home/page/`) and use it in the jQuery `.load` statement.

```
<div id="Footer">
    <div id="partToBeReplacedWithLoadData">
        @Html.Partial("_FooterReport")
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery load statement:

```
$('#Footer').load('/home/page/ #partToBeReplacedWithLoadData');
```

You won't be able to just request the file in the project. It should go through a route first. If you had a route and an action in a controller that returned only the footer partial that would work, too (something like: `/home/footer/`).

This will not reload the whole page, but get just the contents of the `#Footer` div.

Comment: that is ok but partial is in my shared folder ( default folder in mvc project) how can i get address of Home??? what can I write instead of Home???